# Export to PDF issue in SSRS

Tags: pdf, reporting-services, export

I am having two list side by side and having matrix inside it.Depending on some calculation i am hiding the list.In reportviewer i am getting correct output but when i export to PDF the list which i hided through some calculation is also getting exported .It's killing me. You can get clear idea by the belowImage

In report Viewer

http://s8.postimg.org/d53e2jput/image.png

After exporting to PDF

http://s30.postimg.org/5gwy6uz0h/image.png

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Open the **Tablix Properties**
2. Select the **Visibility Tab**
3. Select **Show or hide based on an expression**
4. Insert `=IIf((Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "PDF" AND <Enter your calculation condition>) OR <Enter your calculation condition>, True, False)`